# Finding the Least amount of the same 20 ball taken

Tags: probability, statistics, random

I found this neat question on my test, anyone can solve it? Many solutions with different ways to solve is welcomed and **needed**.

In a bag there are $200$ marbles consisting of $60$ red marbles, $60$ blue marbles, $60$ green marbles, and the rest are $20$ white marbles and yellow (white and yellow in $1$ marbles). If the marble is chosen without looking, what is the **minimum** amount that must be taken in order from the selected minimum marbles consists of $20$ marbles of the same color?

- **A.)** $58$
- **B.)** $57$
- **C.)** $68$
- **D.)** $78$
- **E.)** $79$

**Please Show Your Work!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game is to get $20$ marbles with the same color,  we pick them one by one and we stop as soon as we reach the $20$'s.  There is a worst-case scenario-in terms of number of picks- that will lead to the win.

First, we are so unlucky that we pick all yellows and whites, that is $20$ taken.Worse, we pick $19$ reds, $19$ blues ,and $19$ greens. The next pick is a winning one as we will either have $20$ reds,blues or greens.

Therefore , the number of picks in the worst case scenario that leads to the win is 
$$20+19*3+1=78$$